# Embed a View into a render array

Tags: views, 8, theming

In Drupal 7, I used the following code implementing views_embed_view in a render array.

```
  $view_output = views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id, $uid);

  $page['profile']['bio_mobile'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => $view_output,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="mobile-display">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
```

How do I do that using Drupal 8?  Although the function is still documented, it return nothing more than just the array I passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about using `#markup` but I can create a variable with a renderable View array like so:

```
  // Staff snippet.
  $view = Views::getView('staff');
  $view->setDisplay('user_snippet');
  $view->preExecute();
  $view->execute();

  if (count($view->result)) {
    $variables['user_snippet'] = $view->buildRenderable('user_snippet');
  }
```

Then in the twig file I am sending the variable to:

```
{% if user_snippet %}
  {{ user_snippet }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Seems so complicated compared to the good old days of Drupal 6 and 7. However, that may be the best (only) way... 

So, how do you "send the variable" to a twig file?

Comment: I actually think this is better. If you check the old function it just calls this code anyway. This was done in a preprocess hook for a node. It calls ‘buildRenderable’ to fetch a renderable array of that View. It’s added to the $variables array, which is what is sent to Twig.

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution. Though the answer from noSsseat also works. It *seems* that there is more control here with the use of the template... The only thing that really bothers me is that I can not figure out *how* it is working.  We are passing the Twig Template an array... how does it "know" what to do with it?  I can pass a simple string to it (like "hello world") and it works... magic powers???   Thank you for the help!

Comment: The `$variables` is just an array of items for a template. It can be any value and it can also be a renderable array. The `buildRenderable` method returns a renderable array for that View. The information on how to render it is inside the array, which means it works the same way as rendering content in a node like `{{ content.FIELD_NAME }}`. Any preprocess hook for Views to change how its theming or what its theming should still work. Drupal 7 worked the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, `#markup` only allows string, but you can by using a block type

```
  $entityTypeManager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
  $viewExecutableFactory = \Drupal::service('view.executable');

  $view = $entityTypeManager->getStorage('view')->load($view_name);
  $view = $viewExecutableFactory->get($display_id);
  $view->setArguments([$uid]);
  $view->preExecute();
  $view->execute();

  $page['profile']['bio_mobile'] = [
    '#type' => 'block',
    'content' => [
      'system_main' => $view_output,
     ],
    '#cache' => $view->getCacheTags(),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="mobile-display">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];
```

Comment: Bingo!  I knew there had to be a way to digest the output from that function. I'm guessing there are existing #themes that would probably handle it as well.  I'm favoring the first answer because it gives more flexibility with the theme file that I would have had to build into the view before embedding it. 
Thank you helping - I'll probably use that logic in another spot.